# How do I get a list of all the partitioned tables in my database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning, metadata

How do I get a list of all the partitioned tables in my database?

Which system tables/DMVs should I be looking at?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This query should give you what you want:

```
select distinct t.name
from sys.partitions p
inner join sys.tables t
on p.object_id = t.object_id
where p.partition_number <> 1
```

The `sys.partitions` catalog view gives a list of all partitions for tables and most indexes.  Just JOIN that with `sys.tables` to get the tables.

All tables have at least one partition, so if you are looking specifically for partitioned tables, then you'll have to filter this query based off of `sys.partitions.partition_number <> 1` (for non-partitioned tables, the `partition_number` is always equal to 1).

Comment: this returned 50K objects and something about it doesn't feel right to me. We are in the middle of a Peoplesoft Finance db upgrade from sql 2005 to 2008 R2 and it seems the newer version of people tools doesn't support partitioned tables. Is there any other way to identify the portioned tables?

Comment: @yogirk So sorry, typo there.  See my edit.  Instead of `partition_id` in your WHERE clause you need `partition_number`.  My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and I am glad there are few tables to tackle, just like I expected :)

Comment: @yogirk Have fun with that!

Comment: There is an error here - table is still can be partitioned (using PF and PS) but having single partition. So for those tables the query returns wrong results

Comment: @OlegDok I wouldn't say this is error - for some cases this is OK to search only for tables with more than one partition. But yes, for original question this query can be considered as wrong

Answer (score 35):

Methinks a better query is as follows:

```
select object_schema_name(i.object_id) as [schema],
    object_name(i.object_id) as [object],
    i.name as [index],
    s.name as [partition_scheme]
    from sys.indexes i
    join sys.partition_schemes s on i.data_space_id = s.data_space_id
```

This looks at the 'proper' place to identify the partition scheme: [`sys.partition_schemes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189752.aspx), it has the right cardinality (no need for `distinct`), it shows *only* partitioned object (no need for a filtering `where` clause), it projects the schema name and partition scheme name. Note also how this query highlights a flaw on the original question: it is not *tables* that are partitioned, but *indexes* (and this includes index 0 and 1, aka. heap and clustered index). A table can have multiple indexes, some partitioned some not.

Comment: This is the right answer instead of the 1st one - taking into account if the table is ON partition scheme instead of filegroup

Answer (score 3):

Well, then how about combining the 2:

```
select 
    object_schema_name(i.object_id) as [schema],
    object_name(i.object_id) as [object_name],
    t.name as [table_name],
    i.name as [index_name],
    s.name as [partition_scheme]
from sys.indexes i
    join sys.partition_schemes s on i.data_space_id = s.data_space_id
    join sys.tables t on i.object_id = t.object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article while searching for this type of script and worked from a few resources to create these from a SQL 2019 server.

```
-- List partitioned tables (excluding system tables)

SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM sys.partitions sp
       JOIN sys.objects so ON so.object_id = sp.object_id
       where name NOT LIKE 'sys%' and name NOT LIKE 'sqla%' and name NOT LIKE 'plan%' 
       and name NOT LIKE 'persistent%' and name NOT LIKE 'queue_messages%'
       and name NOT LIKE 'ifts%' and name NOT LIKE 'fulltext%'
       ORDER BY name


-- List partitioned tables and partition information (excluding system tables)

SELECT so.name
      ,[partition_id]
      ,sp.[object_id]
      ,[index_id]
      ,[partition_number]
      ,[hobt_id]
      ,[rows]
      ,[filestream_filegroup_id]
      ,[data_compression]
      ,[data_compression_desc]
  FROM sys.partitions sp
       JOIN sys.objects so ON so.object_id = sp.object_id
       where name NOT LIKE 'sys%' and name NOT LIKE 'sqla%' and name NOT LIKE 'plan%' 
       and name NOT LIKE 'persistent%' and name NOT LIKE 'queue_messages%'
       and name NOT LIKE 'ifts%' and name NOT LIKE 'fulltext%'
       ORDER BY name
```

I hope they are helpful.